# How do I play this tab of No More Sorrow's Live version

Tags: electric-guitar, tablature

I'm trying to play the live version of Linkin Park's No More Sorrow.

Tuning is half step down drop D

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|-9--9--9--9--9--9--9-------------------------------------|
|-x--x--x--x--x--x--x-------------------------------------|
|-7--7--7--7--7--7--7-------------------------------------|
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

How do I play this with a full strum?

I'm having trouble muting the other strings and just playing the 9 and 7.

Full tab is shared in the description of the youtube video. Search for variation 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

those x are dead notes, I guess you already know that. They can be a bit tricky to play.
I have seen multiple approaches to play these, but for me the following worked the best when playing these octave-cords:

place your index-finger on the 7th fret on the A-string, and your ring-finger on the 9th fret on the G-string. Be sure, that you use only the tip on your index finger to hold the E on the a string, that way it should mute the D-string automatically. like this:
[image]
(Not the best graphic, but the best I could do in 5 minutes; I hope this explains it better than my words)

And do whatever you like with the rest of your fingers. :) (For example: mute the other strings)
I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

I watched the video now, it seems he uses a similiar technique. It looks like he is using the pinky for the 9th fret/G-string, and the remaining fingers to mute the low E-string (for me, that works better than using the thumb for such cords, too; I mostly use the middle-finger only, though) and also the pinky for the B- and high E-string. With this technique he can play a full strum.